# Stop forms from clearing on submit

Tags: asp.net, html, forms

I'm using asp.net, but just using regular forms rather than runat="server" ones. Here is one:

```
<form action="addUser.aspx" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <label>Username</label>
        <input name="username" type="text" maxlength="50" />
        <span id="usernameInfo" class="fieldInfo" runat="server"></span>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input name="password" type="password" maxlength="50" />
        <span id="passwordInfo" class="fieldInfo" runat="server"></span>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="50" />
        <span id="emailInfo" class="fieldInfo" runat="server"></span>
    </fieldset>

    <div class="buttonHolder">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <span id="generalInfo" runat="server"></span>
    </div>

</form>
```

When the form is submited and the page reloads, all the fields in the form are empty. This is annoying because I need to do validate the form and inform the user if the username is already in user, for instance.

Why is this happening? Even if I take out all the code that processes the form, it is still cleared on submit. On the web, the difficultly people have is the opposite - they want forms to clear when they aren't.

Why is the inverse happening for me, and how do I fix it?

Comment: The code that's processing the submitted form would make this easier to diagnose (especially since you aren't using server controls).  If you need to you can use Fiddler to verify that the http post contains your forms data.

Comment: @KenHenderson I can see that the form data is getting to the server. The problem is that it clears it from the user's browser when the page refreshes. even if I take out all the form processing code, this still happens.

Comment: Personally I would go with Bobby's answer below.  But as L Johnson alluded to if you are not using the server controls you are responsible for populating them with the posted data before the page finishes processing on the server if you want it to appear.

Comment: @KenHenderson Ah, I see. I incorrectly assumed that the default behavior was the other way around - fields are left populated after submitting a form unless explicitly cleared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your answer its not clear as to why you are using html inputs. But if you can use asp.net controls I would recommend using this.

```
<asp:TextBox id="textbox" runat="server" />
```

instead of this

```
<input type="text" maxlength="50" />
```

With asp.net textbox control viewstate will take care of preserving your value in textbox even after you click submit but stay on the same page becasue of validation errors. when you move off to another page and come page you will lose your values.

more info on viewstate here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The email does  the "name" attribute is the one necessary to read the post.

You didn't provide any code that shows how you are trying to read the values, which I am assuming you are trying to read in the code behind.

You should be able to read the value as Request["NameOfControl"].

Are you setting the values when the page loads, that may overwrite the inputted values?

READING THE ABOVE COMMENTS:

You would have to re-populate the controls using javascript since the controls aren't server-side..  Since you are not using webcontrols with runat="server", there is no ViewState, so you have the re-populating of values manually.